# Can I use a Wildcard in CMD when looking for a folder that has a Timestamp on it?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command, wildcard

I'm trying to move a file from one location to another folder that was created with a timestamp in CMD.

At its simplest form, it looks like this:

```
move C:\temp\version.txt C:\temp\DB-backup*\version.txt
```

It gives me the error that "the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

I"m really pretty new at using wildcards at all and a lot of what I've already researched doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: A date in a file or folder name makes only sense when there is more than one (to distinguish them). Trying to use a wildcard means, you want to copy it into all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.  :)

Long answer: What you're trying to do is a little vague, because it is unclear if there are other folders with the same naming convention. So here is one solution, which finds the most recently created folder that matches the naming convention "DB-backup(somestuffafter)"

```
mv version.txt (Get-ChildItem -path C:\temp\checkdirs | where {$_.Name -match "DB-backup(.*)"} | sort -property creationtime -descending | select name -first 1).name
```

Yes, that's a little much for a one-liner, so let's unpack it a bit:

```
(                                                  # parens to capture the object
Get-ChildItem -path C:\temp\checkdirs -Directory | # get list of directories
where {$_.Name -match "DB-backup(.*)"} |           # that MATCH the naming convention
sort -property creationtime -descending |          # reverse sort by creationtime
select name -first 1                               # select the first one in the list
).name                                             # then we only want the value of 'name'
```

The MATCH can obviously be much more complex, and handled with regex.  This solves the problem if you're only looking to isolate by the creationtime property.

But if you want to sort on partial text of the actual filename, that will likely require a capture, save capture and filename to hash, then sort the hash by the capture, but use the filename.  Please give more specifics if that is your question.  :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did eventually have to use powershell to accomplish what I needed. The software that I use has limitations that it can't run powershell itself, so I have to have a cmd script that calls the ps1 file. Which is mostly what I was trying to avoid. I just set a $date variable and had it search for the folder that ended in today's date. It ended up being convoluted but functional :')

Comment: @Installer: same can be done in `cmd`. If you need help with it, you have to tell us the exact format of `db-backup...` (how exactly does the date look like).

Comment: @Installer, yw and be careful about user context between cmd and powershell.  depending on the app you're working with and security layers, switching between them can cause additional headaches.  Best way I've found is to use a cmd wrapper to call the entire .ps1.  But if it requires going in and out of cmd <> .ps1, then it seems best to load up the one-liners and increase the error reporting.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in PowerShell:

```bsh
dir C:\temp\DB-backup* | foreach { copy C:\temp\version.txt $_ }
```

and then delete the source (since you want to 'move' it):

```
del C:\temp\version.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) wildcard can only be used in the last element of a path.

To work around that you could first use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve the parent directory path and then build the final file path, like this:

```cmd
for /D %I in ("C:\temp\DB-backup*") do move "C:\temp\version.txt" "%~I\version.txt"
```

Note that this would try to move the text file multiple times if there are more than one directories matching the pattern `DB-backup*`, but it would fail, of course, because the file has already been removed from the source location. If this could happen you could copy the file instead and delete it afterwards:

```cmd
set "ERR=" & (for /D %I in ("C:\temp\DB-backup*") do copy "C:\temp\version.txt" "%~I\version.txt" & if ErrorLevel 1 set "ERR=#") & if not defined ERR del "C:\temp\version.txt"
```

The [`if ErrorLevel 1` check](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) checks if copying succeeded and sets a flag-like variable `ERR` if not; so the following command only executes only in case all the preceding ones succeeded. This means if at least one `copy` action fails the source file is not deleted.

To use the above code fragments in a batch file, make sure to double the `%`-signs of the `for /D` variable `%I`.